# rsync backup bash script reading options from another file

Tags: bash, scripting, backup, rsync

I´m trying to make a script that ssh to multiple server and run a backup of them. The server has different folders that should be included.

I´m trying to do this with 2 files one that specify the hostname and the folders that should be included in the backup.

```
[SERVER]
HOST=server1
SOURCE="/home"
SOURCE="/etc"

[SERVER]
HOST=server2
SOURCE=/home"
SOURCE="/etc"
SOURCE="/var"

[EOF]
```

And one file that reads from this file and execute the backup.

```
while read host
do
        for i in
                 rsync -chazP --fake-super --rsync-path="sudo rsync" --stats backup@$host:/home  /var/backup/$host/
        done
done < /var/backup/testscripts/hosts
```

This is the first version of the script that worked when the options file only had hostname in it.

How can I make the script so it read the host variable and then read 1 SOURCE line and executes the backup and then read the next SOURCE line and run it again. When it reads [SERVER] it should start over and when it comes to [EOF] it should end.

Iam a beginner at scripting so all help and explanation are welcome.

Comment: I suggest to take a look at `dirvish` to backup servers with rsync.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you attack this problem from a different angle to make it simpler.

First, make `/var/backup/testscripts/hosts` a directory, not a file.  Then, for each host, create a config file named "SERVERNAME.backup_config".  The content of each of these files would be something like this :

```
/home
/etc
```

Essentially, just a list of directories to backup to that host.  That would get rid of the need to parse the config files.

```
config_dir=/var/backup/testscripts/hosts
for config_file in "$config_dir"/*.backup_config
do
  host=${config_file##*/}
  host=${host%.backup_config}
  while IFS= read -r dir
  do
    rsync -chazP --fake-super --rsync-path="sudo rsync" --stats backup@host:"$dir" "/var/backup/$host/"
  done<"$config_file"
done
```

Essentially, the idea is to encode your server name in the name of the file, so that the file becomes just a list that can be read one line at a time.  This can be an easy approach to config files for simple cases like these.  In cases where you need more than one list per configured item, you can do one more step : make each server a directory, and use several config files for the various lists you need (and maybe one more config file for everything that is not a list, containing assignments, that can be read sourced with `source` or `.`).

The lines used to assign `host` are shell expansions that get rid of the directory name from the file path, and then remove the extension to exact the server name.  You can find out about it (and a lot more) here: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe.

Please note I have not checked that your `rsync` command is valid, I assume it works for your purpose.

Comment: couldn´t the host=${config_file%/} be written host=$config_file
I tried it in a bash emulator and wrote config_file=/var/backup/files/server1.backup_config 
and got server1 after the filtering. 

Thans so much for your help. Realy good expelantion.

Actualy there´s a problem with the rsync script. When the scripts starts with a user that isnt root (as intended) the files on the backup server has the backup server user as owner. But when copied back to the original server the right owner is back.

Comment: @DragonRapide Honestly, the `host=${config_file%/}` step can be removed: it removes any trailing slash, but in your case there cannot be any trailing slash (I copied if from my personal standard "pure-Bash" `basename` replacement).  I updated the suggested code to remove it (the following line needs to be modified due to the removal).

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly, this solution doesn't scale well, however you have everything in one file and you don't need to bother with reading config files in bash.

```
function my_rsync() {
    rsync -chazP --fake-super --rsync-path="sudo rsync" --stats "$1" "$2"
}


declare -a SERVERS=(
    "server1"
    "server2"
);

declare -a SOURCES1=(
    "/home"
    "/etc"
);

declare -a SOURCES2=(
    "/home"
    "/etc"
    "/var"
);


for SERVER in "${SERVERS[@]}"; do

    case "$SERVER" in
        "server1")
            for SOURCE in "${SOURCES1[@]}"; do
                my_rsync backup@$SERVER:$SOURCE /var/backup/$SERVER/
            done
        ;;
        "server2")
            for SOURCE in "${SOURCES2[@]}"; do
                my_rsync backup@$SERVER:$SOURCE /var/backup/$SERVER/
            done
        ;;
    esac

done
```

Another solution would be to use include files with rsync (`--include-from=FILE     read include patterns from FILE`)
and create one includefile for each server and name them e.g. `server1.txt`/`server2.txt` etc.
Then you wouldn't need the switch/case block and could write something like this (not tested!):

```
for SERVER in "${SERVERS[@]}"; do

    rsync -chazP --fake-super --rsync-path="sudo rsync" --stats --include-from=/path/to/$SERVER.txt backup@$SERVER /var/backup/$SERVER/

done
```